# Creating an sqlite3 table in c++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm experimenting with C++, having recently moved across from python; currently writing a function that builds a table in an sqlite3 database.

I seem to be hitting some newbie errors:

```
int db_build()
{
   sqlite3 *db;
   int rc; // This line
   int sql; // This line
   rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

   /* Create SQL statement */
   sql = "CREATE TABLE WORDS("  \
         "ID INT PRIMARY        KEY      NOT NULL," \
         "CURRENT_WORD          TEXT     NOT NULL," \
         "BEFORE_WORD           TEXT     NOT NULL," \
         "AFTER_WORD            TEXT     NOT NULL," \
         "OCCURANCES            INT      NOT NULL);";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql);
   sqlite3_close(db);
   return 0;
}
```

My terminal returns the following:

```
akf@akf-v5 ~/c/HelloWorld $ g++ main.cpp -l sqlite3
main.cpp: In function ‘int db_build()’:
main.cpp:30:8: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
    sql = "CREATE TABLE WORDS("  \
        ^
main.cpp:38:29: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql);
                             ^
main.cpp:38:29: error: too few arguments to function ‘int sqlite3_exec(sqlite3*, const char*, int (*)(void*, int, char**, char**), void*, char**)’
In file included from main.cpp:4:0:
/usr/include/sqlite3.h:379:16: note: declared here
 SQLITE_API int sqlite3_exec(
                ^
```

If I change 'int sql' to 'char sql' I hit even more errors. Any idea how to get this thing going?

Comment: Explain what you're trying to do here: `sql = "CREATE TABLE WORDS("`.  Now given whatever explanation you have, how can a string be an `int`?

Comment: Thanks for the query @PaulMcKenzie, 1. I'm trying to create an SQL string command. 2. I also tried that with char and string, both of which incurred new errors. I interpreted "uninitialized const" as INT being the required variable type declaration - not sure how I came to this conclusion, it was one of those spur of the moment things haha

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have one syntax error.  Get rid of the trailing `\`

```c
/* Create SQL statement */
sql = "CREATE TABLE WORDS("  
      "ID INT PRIMARY        KEY      NOT NULL," 
      "CURRENT_WORD          TEXT     NOT NULL," 
      "BEFORE_WORD           TEXT     NOT NULL," 
      "AFTER_WORD            TEXT     NOT NULL," 
      "OCCURANCES            INT      NOT NULL);";
```

And one python-y error.  Change `int sql;` to:

```
const char sql[];
```

The type `const char sql[]` is appropriate for constant string literals.

*Edit:*

For completeness, Hot Licks also hints that your call to `sqlite3_exec` must be:

```
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to code in C++ you'd better very quickly learn what a pointer is, and what a "C string" is.

`sqlite3_exec` expects a C string as the second argument, which is a sequence of 8-bit `char` values terminated with a byte of zeros.  It is passed via a pointer-to-char -- `char *`.

So your declaration needs to be `char * sql;`.

Also, if you look at [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) you will see that `sqlite3_exec` has several more parameters -- they cannot be omitted (though they can be passed as `NULL`).